# Autopost Wordpress blog posts in Facebook page - plugins not working since i use subdomain

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, plugins, app-id

I have a subdomain http://www.deals.gbhaskar.com and am trying to autopost the recent blog posts from Wordpress blog to Facebook page using Wordpress plugins but am unable to achieve.

Have searched a lot to find the solution but dint get a right one.

Solutions tried so far,

1. Tried many wordpress plugins for posting recent blog posts.
2. Have filled the details in wordpress plugins which includes APP ID and SECRET KEY.
3. Getting an error saying that url has error and it is pointing to "http://gbhaskar.com" instead of "http://www.deals.gbhaskar.com".
4. Changed the Site URL in developers section in facebook.

After all still throws error saying that Wordpress cannot authorize my subdomain.

If any other details are required, let me know.

Comment: If you run your URL through the Open Graph Object Debugger you will see some errors, for example that you define multiple og:urls. I'd say fix the error(s) and try again. Also, could you add the error description you see? Or a screenshot of the error message? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.deals.gbhaskar.com%2F